How many times should you play to be sure of winning and losing at least once?
I started with the binomial pdf (assume $p$ denotes probability of success):
$P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}$
Then plugged in the counter probability, so that we don't get a win or loss:
$P(X = 0) = \binom{n}{0} p^0 (1 - p)^{n - 0}$
Since we want to avoid that case, we need this to be smaller than $\alpha$. Thus:
$(1 - p)^{n} \leq \alpha$
$n \geq \frac{log(\alpha)}{log(1-p)} $
Doing a sanity check where $\alpha=0.05$ and $p=0.5$, gives you n should be at least $5$, which seems reasonable. But I am unsure whether I am really taking care of both cases, i.e. at least 1 success and 1 fail. Can someone shed some light on this?

Guessing that $p$ is the probability of winning and that each game is independent of all others, the probability of $n$ straight wins is $p^n$ and the probability of $n$ straight losses is $(1-p)^n$ so the probability of failure (in the sense of the question) is the sum $F(n)=p^n+(1-p)^n$.   So, you need $n$ such that $F(n)≤(1-\alpha)$.

What do you mean by "be $\alpha%$ sure" of a thing?

The question is a bit confusing, but I could not come up with a better formulation. What I mean is: Say you absolutely want a son and a daughter. How many children do you need to plan to have, in order to get a probability larger than 95% that this will be the case. Hope that is a bit clearer.

The chance of winning them all is $p^n$ and the chance of losing them all is $(1-p)^n$.  As these are mutually exclusive the chance of either one is the sum, $p^n+(1-p)^n$.  It is this you want smaller than $0.05$.  If $p=0.5$ these terms are equal.  If $p$ is rather different from $0.5$ one of them will be much smaller than the other.  Without either of those I think you will have to do a numeric solution.
